# Administering IIS 6.0 on XP 64 bit from Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, iis-6

I have IIS 6.0 running on an XP professional 64 bit machine that I would like to administer from a Windows 7 machine.  Is there an MMC Snap-In I can use for this?

I've found solutions for Win 7 to Server 2003/2008 for IIS 6.0 (Remote Server Administration Tools), but not for XP.

Answer (score 0):

Windows XP ships with IIS 5.1 which is a limited version of the server designed for development work, because of this as far as I know there is no way to remotely manage IIS on this platform.

I believe the only options are management over RDP or upgrading to a Server OS for a full IIS Server.

Comment: Actually it has IIS 6.0, which I believe is what ships with XP Pro 64 bit.  I have been able to remotely administer it from another XP machine (after installing IIS 6.0 manager on it)

Comment: Ah, I've not used the 64 Bit version so I presumed it was still 5.1. Are you running Windows 7 x64 or x86?

Comment: I'm running the 32 bit version of Windows 7

Comment: I believe you're restricted to Remote Desktop. Because IIS is so fundamentally different between 6 and 7, you'd need an IIS 6 box to connect to the XP one. That's my experience anyway.

Comment: Yeah, I can confirm this - I tested it today and I couldn't get connection from Windows 7 to XP machine. RDP is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

XP x64 edition was based on the same code as 2003 SP1, which is why it ships with IIS 6.0 instead of 5.1.

So, if you have a tool that can manage IIS 6.0 (as you mentioned with RSAT), it should run against the XP installation. Doesn't matter that it was designed for 2003 server, functionally they should look (near) identical.

The other possibility - which I almost hate myself for mentioning, but I've started now - is that the IIS 6 Management Console included with IIS 7 might be usable remotely.

What is for certain is that the IIS Manager for IIS 7 in Windows 7 will *not* manage an IIS 6 installation.